# Issue with SMTP server?

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, smtp, gmail

I've tried using SSL:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=******@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=***************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

I've tried using TLS

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=******@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=***************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

With SSL I got this error:

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]
```

With TLS I got this error:

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

Comment: Are you using a cloud server, if so whose ?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail SMTP does not work again. 
You can use MailGun, They give you free 100k email per month. You will have to verify your domain and link your credit card to start sending.

http://mailgun.com/